# Java Abstract Method Parameter Type

Tags: java, abstract-class, abstract-methods, generic-type-argument

I'm having an issue implementing an Abstract Class. I'm declaring an Abstract Method with List as a parameter in the AbstractClass, but when I implement it, it gives me compile errors saying I've not properly implemented the abstract cass im extending.

```
public abstract class MyAbstractClass<T> {
    abstract protected List<T> MyMethod(List<String> list);
}

public class MyClass<MyObject> extends MyAbstractClass {
    @Override
    protected List<MyObject> MyMethod(List<String> list){
        //Do Stuff
    }
}
```

Whenever I implement it automagically it makes the `List<String>` to just `List`.
Is there any reason for this? Thanks.

Comment: Please show how you "implement" it. I'd guess you're using raw types.

Comment: You probably want public class MyClass extends MyAbstractClass<MyObject> {

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you want is this:

```
public class MyClass extends MyAbstractClass<MyObject> {
     @Override
     protected List<MyObject> MyMethod(List<String> list){
      //Do Stuff
    }

}
```

Comment: :P Yeah that was it. I didn't think that would solve my problem as it was complaining about a parameter that had nothing to do with MyObject.

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant to say

```
public class MyClass extends MyAbstractClass<MyObject>
```

which would say that `MyClass` uses `MyObject` for the type parameter `T`.

What you've said is that `MyClass` has a type parameter, which has no relationship to the base class's type parameter `T`.  So in that case, a `MyAbstractClass` reference could point to a `MyClass` instance, and users of that reference needn't know they have a `MyClass` so they can't be constrained by `T` having to be `MyClass`.

Answer (score 0):

change it to

```
extends MyAbstractClass<MyObject>
```

tested it in Eclipse and that works.

It also seems logic, since the superclass can only know what type you want to return if you give it that type. And if you don't give it a type it has to generalise.

Answer (score 0):

The question has ambiguity so I am answering two possible cases

1. MyObject is a class

   `public class MyClass extends MyAbstractClass<MyObject> {
       @Override
       protected List<MyObject> MyMethod(List<String> list) {
           // do stuff
       }
   }`
2. You used MyObject just as a generic and named it like this then,
   same type is passed to the parent as below

   `public class MyClass<MyObject> extends MyAbstractClass<MyObject> {
       @Override
       protected List<MyObject> MyMethod(List<String> list) {
          // do stuff
       }
   }`